# De-Activate Physics on SpriteKit

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, game-physics

i wanna dis-activate the physic of node for a while .Please help me figure that out .

```
  SKSpriteNode * node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"blade.png"];
    node.size = CGSizeMake(30, 30);
    node.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:node.size];
    node.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    node.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CharacterCategory;
    node.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ObjectCategory;
    node.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CharacterCategory;
    node.position = nd.Position;
    node.physicsBody.mass = 10000;
    SKAction * actfadein = [SKAction fadeInWithDuration:nd.FadeInDuration];
    SKAction * actfadeout = [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:nd.FadeOutDuration];
    SKAction * wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:3];
    SKAction * removephy = [SKAction runBlock:^(void){
        // i tried to removeFromParent but it never comes back
    }];
    SKAction * activatephy = [SKAction runBlock:^(void){
        //[self addChild:node];
    }];
    SKAction * myActions = [SKAction sequence:@[actfadeout,removephy,wait,activatephy,actfadein]];
    [node runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:myActions]];
    [FadeObjects addChild:node];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the `physicsBody` property of the `SKSpriteNode` to nil. If you later need to apply physics again, just assign another `physicsBody`.

Answer (score -1):

Set this:

```
node.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
```